# Notepad++ Force every file format to selected one when opening any file type

Tags: notepad++, format

I would like to format every opened file in Notepad++ (all files regardless of their extension) to eg. batch or VBS format. Is there a way to achieve that? 
I've found a setting for formatting new documents, but I want to format opened text files as structured language document.

The reason for that, is that I like visual highlighting data eg. in VBS format when I'm opening my text files, that often includes php code, numeric data  etc. and that would help me a lot.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and clarify exactly what you want. Do you want to have **all files regardless of their extension** to have "batch" syntax highlights? The format of an opened already existing file depends on its extension. You cannot change the behaviour of the built in extensions listed in the "Settings" -> "Style Configurator" dialog.

Comment: yes, exacly this is what i would like to achieve.

Comment: is there a way to force notepad++ to treat .txt files as eg. VBS ?

Comment: Please remember to include `@user` (example @DavidPostill) in your comment if you want to notify a particular user. Otherwise they may not see your comment. I had to come looking for this update. :(

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there a way to force notepad++ to treat .txt files as VBS?

Use the "Style Configurator" dialog:

1. Go to "Settings" > "Style Configurator"
2. Select "Language" > "VB / VBS"
3. Add "txt" to "User ext:."
4. Click "Save & Close"

   [image]

Comment: and how to format every oponed file as vbs...?

Comment: @infografik For each opened file, menu "Language" > "VB"

Answer (score 0):

You could simply click on 'Language' and choose your prefered highlighting after you've opened any file in notepad++.